# Convergence criterion over a finite domain

Tags: limits

Tonight I had a math nightmare (I exaggerate a bit).

Assume the sequence (not series!) $S_i$ takes only values from a finite domain $D$:
$\forall_i S_i\in D, card(D)<\infty$.

The convergence criterion is then very terse: $\exists_n\forall_{i>n}S_i=x(\in D)\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S=x$.

So, in my sleep I had to prove that and began with "The $\Rightarrow$ part is obvious..." but the exam commission consisted of Freddy Krueger and Mr. Crocker saying "Obvious isn't a valid math argument" and I awoke with an "F" carved into my spleen.

So, the $\Rightarrow$ part *is* obvious (just insert the fact that always $S_i=x$ beyond some $n$ into the ["standard" convergence criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition) and verify), and in a *real* exam I surely could prove $\Leftarrow$ by contraposition but my head (and spleen) still hurts...Please save my next night and prove it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a positive distance between members of $D$: There exists $\delta >0$ such that $d_1,d_2 \in D, d_1 \neq d_2 \implies |d_1-d_2| >\delta$. Now there exists $n$ such that $i >n$ implies $|S_i-x| <\delta /2$. If $i, j >n$ the $|S_i-S_j| \leq |S_i-x| +|S_j-x| <\delta$ so $S_i=S_j$. I will let you finish the proof.

Comment: So a clever application of the triangle inequation? (But in that case you have a typo, one i must be j?!)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I have  corrected the typo.